# Collect DYNAMIC data on URL via $_GET without form

Tags: php, html, get

I'm currently blocked on a little problem, I think i'm close to the answer, but still didn't managed to got it.

Here is my issue :

I have few a tags on a page, for each giving $id_customer and $id_project on another page, and on this page I want to collect my data on my url because I need it for my next query.

Unfortunately I'm not using a form to give data, so i can't collect via names.

here is my code :

ON Page who send (I guess this is ok there because I have data on URL)

```
               if($result){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                $id_client=$row['id_client'];
                $id_projet=$row['id_projet'];
                $nom=$row['nom'];
                $adresse_site=$row['adresse_site'];
                $nom_site=$row['nom_site'];
                $vignette_site=$row['vignette_site'];
                $desc_site=$row['desc_site'];
                $en_ligne=$row['en_ligne'];
                $_GET['id_client']=$id_client;
                $_GET['id_projet']=$id_projet;
                ?>

                   <!-- <form method="post" action="projet-in.php" id="form_<?php echo $id_client."-".$id_projet ; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name='client' value="<?php echo $id_client; ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name='projet' value="<?php echo $id_projet; ?>" />
                    </form> -->
                        <input type="hidden" name='client' value="<?php echo $id_client; ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name='projet' value="<?php echo $id_projet; ?>" />
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 bloc-galerie bloc-galerie"><a id="submit" href="projet-in.php?<?php echo $_GET['id_client'].'&'.$_GET['id_projet'] ;?>" />
                                <span class="hover-galerie">
                                    <p>Site</p>
                                    <p class="texte-rose"><span class="nom-site"><?php echo $nom_site; ?></span><br /><?php echo $adresse_site; ?></p>
                                    <p><?php echo $desc_site; ?></p>
                                </span>
                                <img src="images/<?php echo $vignette_site; ?>" alt="<?php echo $nom; ?>" /></a>
                            </div>
                <?php 
            }

        }
        else{       
            echo "NON";
        }
       ?>
```

THEN ON MY SECOND PAGE (here is the issue) :

```
       include('menu.php'); 
          $id_client=$_GET[0];
          $id_projet=$_GET[1];
          $query="SELECT * FROM db_clients where id_client=$id_client and id_projet=$id_projet";
          $result=mysqli_query($connexion, $query);

        if($result){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){


                $adresse_site=$row['adresse_site'];
                $nom_site=$row['nom_site'];
                $lien_site=$row['lien_site'];
                $chapeau=$row['chapeau'];
                $devices=$row['devices'];
                $img_accueil=$row['img_accueil'];
                $img_collection=$row['img_collection'];
                $img_produits=$row['img_produits'];
           ?>
```

Thank you !

EDIT : I tried $_SESSION but every a tag showed the last recurrence on the Session ofc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to name your params in your url :

```
href="projet-in.php?idClient=<?php echo $_GET['id_client'].'&idProject='.$_GET['id_projet'] ;?>"
```

And after, to get it in the project-in page, you have to use the name :

```
$id_client=$_GET['idClient'];
$id_projet=$_GET['idProject'];
```

Comment: Thank you sir! It works, And I did not know that you can name your parameters like that, I have to continue working on PHP!